# How to print out content of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have some response from a server and I have put the response in the content of iframe. Essentially what I need is the item number (see screenshot below), in this case it's 13.

[image]

So I tried doing `console.log($("#iframe").contents());` which prints out: 
 [image]

I have tried looking through this but cannot find the item number. Is there a easier way to get to the `body` and obtain the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JQuery approach and it's very simple

```
// this will get you item = 13
var result = $("#iframe").contents().find("pre").html(); 

// this will get you 13
result = result.split("=")[1]; 

// 13
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question:

1. There is an `<iframe>`
2. The `<iframe>` has content in a string (i.e. `item = 13`) that's in a `<pre>`
3. **But** you just want the number from said string (i.e. `13`);

The following Demo 1 accomplishes the objectives listed above using plain JavaScript and Demo 2 uses jQuery.

**Note:** jQuery can be significantly slower than JavaScript which is apparent when dealing with loading iframes. Keep in mind that iframes are the slowest part of your load time. If it doesn't look like you are getting the iframe at all, then run your iframe dependant functions at `window.onload`.

**Also of note:** both versions of the function `getNumberFromFrame(iframe, target)` are reusable. You can use this function on a single element within an iframe and if the target element has **any text with numbers✎**, it will extract those numbers regardless of the how the string is patterned.

ex. `"item = 13" // 13`

ex. `"August 23, 2017" //23 2017`

✎ Edited the regular expression on line 33 to replace non-number matches to a space.

**Details are commented in Demo 1 and Demo 2**

### Demo 1: [PLUNKER - Plain JavaScript](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z8vhD17Mp1IBq1wLSjxy/)

### Demo 2: [PLUNKER - jQuery](https://embed.plnkr.co/iBneJeELeDGHVHhL7sX7/)

---

### Demo 1 - Plain JavaScript: STACK

This is provided as site requires us to post code on the answer, **be aware that this copy does not function due to SO security measures**. Please review the functioning [PLUNKER](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z8vhD17Mp1IBq1wLSjxy/) instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Parent Page</h1>
  <iframe id='ifrm1' name='ifrm1' src='child_page.html' width='200' height='200' scrolling='no' frameborder="1"></iframe>
  <br> Result:
  <output id='display'></output>


  <script>
    /* Pass an iframe and it's targeted content as
            || selectors (e.g. "TAG", "#ID", ".CLASS", etc)
            */
    function getNumberFromFrame(iframe, target) {
      // Reference the iframe 
      var iFrm = document.querySelector(iframe);
      /* Reference the iframe's Document Object by
      || using .contentDocument OR 
      || .contentWindow.document properties
      */
      var iDoc = iFrm.contentDocument || iFrm.contentWindow.document;
      /* Now reference the target parameter with
      || the iframe's Document Object.
      */
      var iSel = iDoc.querySelector(target);
      // Get the target's text
      var iTxt = iSel.textContent;
      // Then filter out everything but numbers
      var iNum = iTxt.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
      // Ensure it is a number
      iNum = parseFloat(iNum);
      // Return number.
      return iNum;
    }

    /* When Window Object is loaded:
    || Call getNumberFromFrame()
    */
    window.onload = function() {
      var result = getNumberFromFrame('#ifrm1', 'pre');
      var view = document.getElementById('display');
      view.textContent = result;

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2 - jQuery: STACK

This is provided as site requires us to post code on the answer, **be aware that this copy does not function due to SO security measures**. Please review the functioning [PLUNKER](https://embed.plnkr.co/iBneJeELeDGHVHhL7sX7/) instead

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Parent Page</h1>
  <iframe id='ifrm1' name='ifrm1' src='child_page.html' width='200' height='200' scrolling='no' frameborder="1"></iframe>
  <br> Result:
  <output id='display'></output>

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script>
    /* Pass an iframe and it's targeted content as
        || selectors (e.g. "TAG", "#ID", ".CLASS", etc)
        */
    function getNumberFromFrame(iframe, target) {
      /* .contents() method "opens" iframe 
      || .find() will find the specified target
      || inside of iframe.
      */
      var iEle = $(iframe).contents().find(target);
      // Get text of target
      var iTxt = iEle.text();
      //console.log(iTxt);
      /* Replace anything that's not a number with
      || nothing.
      */
      var iNum = iTxt.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
      // Ensure it is a number
      //console.log(iNum)
      var iRes = parseFloat(iNum);
      // Return number.
      return iNum;
    }

    // When Window Object is loaded...
    /* Find the element with the id of #display
    || Set output#display text to the return of
    || getNumberFromFrame('#ifrm', 'pre')
    */

    window.onload = function() {
      $('#display').text(getNumberFromFrame('#ifrm1', 'pre'));
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you do this in JQuery?

Comment: @KevinB I posted a JQuery only answer

Comment: @KevinB, your tags are: [javascript], [jquery], [html], and [iframe]. As you probably already know, jQuery is JavaScript and my example will work with or without jQuery loaded. If time permits, I'll add jQuery in as well.

Comment: @KevinB as promised a jQuery version, happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
console.log($("#iframe")["0"].contentDocument.body.firstElementChild.innerText);
```

[Working evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYwnT.png)

Comment: Why the -1? It works. If you don't know how to separate item from 13 just ask, or better, search it.